# Значение и происхождение слова "сторица"

Tags: этимология

Значение и происхождение слова "сторица"

Answer (score 2):

Сторица — ж. устар.
Вознаграждение, возмещение, превышающее ущерб, убытки во много раз (буквально: в сто раз, в стократном размере).

Стори́ца [обычно в выражении: стори́цей (получи́ть, возда́ть)], др.-русск., ст.-слав. съторица ἑκατονταπλασίων (Мар., Зогр.). Образовано от сто (см.); ср. Дильс, Aksl. Gr. 220 и сл.; Бругман, Grdr. 2, 2, 77. Относительно форманта ср. лит. šimteriópas "ста видов", šimtérgis "столетний", д.-в.-н. huntari ср. р. "сотня, округ", лат. centuria "сотня"; см. Вальде–Гофм. 1, 201; Траутман, ВSW 305.

**Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973.**

Answer (score 1):

**стори́цей**
Наречие; неизменяемое.
*Устар.* (обычно в сочетании с глаголами *окупаться, воздавать, воздаваться* и т. п.), во много раз больше, многократно, с избытком; *букв.* стократно.
[Стоит отметить, что *в современном русском языке существительное **сторица** практически не используется*. Чаще всего это слово употребляется в форме ***неизменяемого наречия: сторИцей и сторИцею.***]

*…всякий раз, когда тебе чего-то не хватает или ты в чём-то нуждаешься, дай то, что ты хочешь сначала, и тебе воздастся **стори́цей**. Это касается всего: денег, улыбки, любви, дружбы*.
(Роберт Киосаки)

Происходит от др.-русск. **сторица** "сотня", ст.-слав. **съторица**.
Образовано от праслав. ***sъto**, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. **съто**, ст.-слав. **съто** (др.-греч. ἑκατόν), русск., укр., белор. **сто** (род. п. мн. ч. **сот**), болг. *сто*, чешск., словацк. *sto*, польск. *sto* (род. п. мн. set), в.-луж., н.-луж. *sto*.

Существует прилагательное ***стори́чный***(*устар*., то же, что стократный):
*И вражды безумной семя

Плод **сторичный** принесло:

Не одно погибло племя

Иль в чужбину отошло.*
(Ф. И. Тютчев. К Ганке)

*А иное упало на добрую землю и, взойдя, принесло плод **сторичный**. Сказав сие, возгласил: кто имеет уши слышать, да слышит!*
(Библия. Ветхий и Новый заветы. Синодальный перевод. Библейская энциклопедия арх. Никифора.)

Comment: Словари фиксируют это слово только в форме неизменяемого наречия: сторИцей и сторИцею. У Ефремовой - сторица.

Comment: Да, конечно, Вы правы. Я подразумевала немного другое, не такое категоричное. Спасибо, подправлю.